# Karma not executing any tests

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I'm having an issue getting any tests to run now that I have Karma starting without any issues. I can see in the command line acknowledging my spec files, however, no tests are being run, seeing "Chrome 53.0.2785 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.005 secs / 0 secs)":

```
> testingexample@0.0.1 test C:\src\testingexample
> tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "karma start karma.conf.js"

[1] [WARNING] Looking up paths with require.resolve() is deprecated.
[1] Please add "systemjs" to your SystemJS config paths.
[1] [WARNING] Looking up paths with require.resolve() is deprecated.
[1] Please add "traceur" to your SystemJS config paths.
[1] 27 09 2016 16:06:07.265:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
[1] 27 09 2016 16:06:07.307:WARN [karma]: Port 9876 in use
[1] 27 09 2016 16:06:07.309:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.3.0 server started at http://localhost:9877/
[1] 27 09 2016 16:06:07.309:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
[1] 27 09 2016 16:06:07.364:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
[1] 27 09 2016 16:06:08.151:INFO [Chrome 53.0.2785 (Windows 7 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket /#r4UrKTjwWvF4GtokAAAA with i
d 75686393
    Chrome 53.0.2785 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.004 secs / 0 secs)
[1] 27 09 2016 16:06:10.172:INFO [watcher]: Changed file "C:/src/testingexample/test/1st.spec.js".
[1] 27 09 2016 16:06:10.194:INFO [watcher]: Changed file "C:/src/testingexample/test/components/header/header.spec.js".
[0] 4:06:10 PM - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
    Chrome 53.0.2785 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.005 secs / 0 secs)
```

Project structure:

```
app/
├── common/
├── components/
|   └── header/
|       ├── header.component.css
|       ├── header.component.html
|       └── header.component.ts
test/
├── components/
|   └── header/
|       └── header.spec.ts
├── models/
└── services/
karma-test-shim.js
karma.conf.js
systemjs.config.js
```

packages.json (likely polluted from trying to get everything to start without errors):

```
{
  "name": "testingexample",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "test": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "test-once": "tsc && karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.20",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "brfs": "^1.4.3",
    "browserify": "^13.1.0",
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "jasmine": "^2.5.2",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-browserify": "^5.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.3",
    "karma-cli": "^0.1.2",
    "karma-htmlfile-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8",
    "karma-systemjs": "^0.15.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "phantomjs": "^2.1.7",
    "protractor": "^3.3.0",
    "traceur": "0.0.111",
    "tslint": "^3.7.4",
    "typescript": "^2.0.2",
    "typings": "^1.0.4",
    "watchify": "^3.7.0"
  }
}
```

karma-test-shim.js (this *seems* pretty standard):

```
// #docregion
// /*global jasmine, __karma__, window*/
Error.stackTraceLimit = 0;

jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 1000;

var builtPath = '/base/app/';

__karma__.loaded = function () { };

function isJsFile(path) {
  return path.slice(-3) == '.js';
}

function isSpecFile(path) {
  return /\.spec\.(.*\.)?js$/.test(path);
}

function isBuiltFile(path) {
  return isJsFile(path) && (path.substr(0, builtPath.length) == builtPath);
}

var allSpecFiles = Object.keys(window.__karma__.files)
  .filter(isSpecFile)
  .filter(isBuiltFile);

System.config({
  baseURL: '/base',
  // Extend usual application package list with test folder
  packages: { 'testing': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' } },

  // Assume npm: is set in `paths` in systemjs.config
  // Map the angular testing umd bundles
  map: {
    '@angular/core/testing': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/common/testing': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/compiler/testing': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/http/testing': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/router/testing': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/forms/testing': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms-testing.umd.js',
  },
});

System.import('systemjs.config.js')
  .then(importSystemJsExtras)
  .then(initTestBed)
  .then(initTesting);

/** Optional SystemJS configuration extras. Keep going w/o it */
function importSystemJsExtras(){
  return System.import('systemjs.config.extras.js')
  .catch(function(reason) {
    console.log(
      'WARNING: System.import could not load "systemjs.config.extras.js"; continuing without it.'
    );
    console.log(reason);
  });
}

function initTestBed(){
  return Promise.all([
    System.import('@angular/core/testing'),
    System.import('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing')
  ])

  .then(function (providers) {
    var coreTesting    = providers[0];
    var browserTesting = providers[1];

    coreTesting.TestBed.initTestEnvironment(
      browserTesting.BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
      browserTesting.platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
  })
}

// Import all spec files and start karma
function initTesting () {
  return Promise.all(
    allSpecFiles.map(function (moduleName) {
      return System.import(moduleName);
    })
  )
  .then(__karma__.start, __karma__.error);
}
```

karma.conf.js:

```
// #docregion
module.exports = function(config) {

  var appBase    = 'app/';       // transpiled app JS and map files
  var appSrcBase = 'app/';       // app source TS files
  var appAssets  = 'app/'; // component assets fetched by Angular's compiler

  var testBase    = 'test/';       // transpiled test JS and map files
  var testSrcBase = 'test/';       // test source TS files

  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['systemjs','jasmine'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-systemjs'),
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-htmlfile-reporter'),
      require('karma-browserify'),
      require('browserify')
    ],

    customLaunchers: {
      // From the CLI. Not used here but interesting
      // chrome setup for travis CI using chromium
      Chrome_travis_ci: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox']
      }
    },
    files: [
      // System.js for module loading
      'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
      'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',

        // Reflect and Zone.js
      'node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',

      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/sync-test.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js',

      // RxJs.
      { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },

      // Angular 2 itself and the testing library
      {pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false},
      {pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false},

      'karma-test-shim.js',


      'test/**/*spec.js'
    ],

    // Proxied base paths for loading assets
    proxies: {
      // required for component assets fetched by Angular's compiler
      "/app/": appAssets
    },

    exclude: [],
    preprocessors: {

    },

    reporters: ['progress', 'html'],

    // HtmlReporter configuration
    htmlReporter: {
      // Open this file to see results in browser
      outputFile: '_test-output/tests.html',

      // Optional
      pageTitle: 'Unit Tests',
      subPageTitle: __dirname
    },

    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  })
}
```

and finally, systemjs.config.js:

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                       'npm:rxjs',
      'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

I know that is a ton to go through - I hope i'm doing something obviously wrong.

Comment: Karma is the test runner and jasmine is the testing framework in which the unit tests are written.  I'll try to provide an answer when I get home if nothing else has helped you.

Comment: In my case there was nothing wrong with Karma/Jasmine settings. My spec file had an error. When I fixed that error test run as expected. Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because karma doesn't look at your spec files like testing file.

When it tells you that it has detected changes :

```
[1] 27 09 2016 16:06:10.194:INFO [watcher]: Changed file "C:/src/testingexample/test/components/header/header.spec.js".
```

It does not mean that it was a test file.

To tell karma which files are test files, you can see in **karma-test-shim.js**

```
var allSpecFiles = Object.keys(window.__karma__.files)
  .filter(isSpecFile)
  .filter(isBuiltFile);
```

It tells karma to load all files and then keep only those that are

- `isSpecFile` : something that ends with `.spec.js`
- `isBuiltFile` : something that is under the build path `/base/app/`

In your case, your test are not in the `app` directory, so you have to remove the `.filter(isBuiltFile)` so karma can handle you **spec.js** as tests.

I looked at my own karma tested project and I found some differencies.

In my **karma.conf.js**

- I do not have any SystemJS plugin.

  ```
  frameworks: ['jasmine'],
  plugins   : [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher')
  ],
  ```
- I have compiled app and test JS added to `files` in place of your `'test/**/*spec.js'`.

  ```
  {pattern: appBase + '**/*.js', included: false, watched: true},
  {pattern: testBase + '**/*.js', included: false, watched: true},
  ```

  I don't know if karma allows pattern without using `{pattern: 'test/**/*spec.js', ...}`.

In my **karma-test-shim.js**

- I do not use a **systemjs.config.extras.js** so I have removed all related code.

Comment: This makes total sense - I thought this was a slam dunk when I first changed it. I removed isBuiltFile and only ran the isSpecFile filter - still getting 0 of 0. I thought maybe something was wrong with my regex and redid that, still not detecting any tests. I'm going to continue fiddling in this area because it feels right - any other suggestions?

Comment: Did you try adding a `console.log(moduleName)` in the `allSpecFiles.map` at the bottom of your **karma-test-shim.js** ? Maybe you have to add some conf in your **systemjs.config.js**, since your tests are not under the `app` directory. With the current conf, I think SystemJS does not know how to load file from `test/*` module.

Comment: console.log(string) *anywhere* in the shim isn't outputting for some reason - i'm starting to think there is something deeper wrong here.

Comment: I looked at my own karma tested project and I found some differencies. I have edited my response for longer explanations. I hope it can help

Comment: For anyone coming in the future, I solved this issue by pulling the Karma Config and shim from https://github.com/angular/quickstart and then following Noémi's advice by removing isBuiltFile filter and changing the folder from 'testing' to 'test'. Thanks a bunch, Noémi.

Answer (score 2):

Would like to contribute with my solution, hope someone find it useful in the future.

First, I started my project using this [setup](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html).

I wanted to place my tests in **spec/** folder following this structure:

```
src
└── app/
    ├── components/
    |       └── app.component.ts
    ├── models/
    └── services/
    main.ts
spec/
└── components/
    └── app.component.spec.ts
karma-test-shim.js
karma.conf.js
systemjs.config.js
```

To make that work I did three changes:

1.- Change default testing folders in **karma.config.js**:

```
...
// Testing helpers (optional) are conventionally in a folder called `testing`
var testingBase    = 'spec/'; // transpiled test JS and map files
var testingSrcBase = 'spec/'; // test source TS files
...
```

2.- Build **spec/** folder while running `npm test`, this is changing **package.json** file:

```
{
  "name": "my app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "build:test": "tsc -p spec/",
    ...
    "test": "concurrently \"npm run build:test\" \"npm run build:watch\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

3.- Create **tsconfig.json** file within **spec/** folder, the information is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  }
}
```

While running `npm test`, **tsc** will build all the *.ts* files generating *.js* and *.js.map*. Later, **karma** will run tests inside **spec/** folder.

Seems tests are running twice, but not sure if something related to this configuration or how angular2 works.

Hope this help someone else.

Cheers. :)